Verifying transformation law for Dirac field
I am trying to verify the Lorentz covariance of the Dirac field \begin{equation}\label{transformation}U(A)\psi(x)U(A^{-1})=D(A^{-1})\psi(\Lambda(A)x)\end{equation}
where $A\in SL(2,\mathbb{C})$, $\Lambda:SL(2,\mathbb{C})\to L_+^\uparrow$ is the projection onto the proper Lorentz group, and $D:SL(2,\mathbb{C})\to GL(4,\mathbb{C})$ is a particular 4-dimensional representation of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$. While I have found several sources which take this identity as a postulate and proceed to derive the necessary properties of $D(A)$, I am trying to go the other way around. That is, I am working with the chiral representation of the gamma matrices in which the map $D(A)$ takes the form $$D(A)=\begin{pmatrix}A&0\\0&(A^\dagger)^{-1}\end{pmatrix}$$
and am trying to verify the identity explicitly.
My problem concerns the transformation of the Dirac spinors $u^s(p)$ and $v^s(p)$
(where $s=\pm\frac{1}{2}$ is the spin projection). These are eigenvectors of $p\!\!\!/$ (using Feynman slash notation) with eigenvalue $\pm m$, where $m=\sqrt{p^2}$. $$(p\!\!\!/-m)u^s(p)=(p\!\!\!/+m)v^s(p)=0$$
The action of $U(A)$ in momentum space is $U(A)f(p)=D(A)f(\Lambda(A)^{-1}p)$. My question concerns the quantity $$U(A)u^s(p)=D(A)u^s(\Lambda(A)^{-1}p)$$
It is straightforward to check that $$D(A)~p\!\!\!/~D(A^{-1})=(\Lambda(A)p)\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!/$$
(the whole thing in parentheses on the right should be slashed but I'm not sure how to add the LateX package on here to make it look better)
Using this, we see that $D(A)u^s(\Lambda(A)^{-1}p)$ is also an eigenvector of $p\!\!\!/$ $$p\!\!\!/ ~D(A)u^s(\Lambda(A)^{-1}p)=D(A)~(\Lambda(A)^{-1}p)\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!{/} ~~~~~ u^s(\Lambda(A)^{-1}p)~=~m~D(A)u^s(\Lambda(A)^{-1}p)$$
Hence we must have that $D(A)u^s(\Lambda(A)^{-1}p)$ is some linear combination of the $u^s(p)$, depending on $A$ and $s$. That is, $$D(A)u^s(\Lambda(A)^{-1}p)=\alpha_{A,s}~u^{1/2}(p)~+~\beta_{A,s}~u^{-1/2}(p)$$
A similar argument holds for the negative energy solutions:
$$D(A)v^s(\Lambda(A)^{-1}p)=\gamma_{A,s}~v^{1/2}(p)~+~\delta_{A,s}~v^{-1/2}(p)$$
My problem is that plugging in the definitions of $D$, $\Lambda$, and $u,v$ does not seem to give the right values of $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, $\delta$ in order to satisfy the transformation law!
To solve for the scalars $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$, we can arrange their defining equations into matrix form:
$$\begin{pmatrix}u^{1/2}(p)~~\mid &u^{-1/2}(p)~~\mid & v^{-1/2}(p)~~\mid&v^{1/2}(p)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_{1/2}&\alpha_{-1/2}&0&0\\\beta_{1/2}&\beta_{-1/2}&0&0\\0&0&\gamma_{-1/2}&\gamma_{1/2}\\0&0&\delta_{-1/2}&\delta_{1/2}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}A&0\\0&(A^\dagger)^{-1}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}u^{1/2}(\Lambda(A)^{-1}p)~~\mid &u^{-1/2}(\Lambda(A)^{-1}p)~~\mid & v^{-1/2}(\Lambda(A)^{-1}p)~~\mid&v^{1/2}(\Lambda(A)^{-1}p)\end{pmatrix}$$
It turns out that with the chiral gamma matrices, one can normalize $u^s(p),v^s(p)$ appropriately so that
$$\begin{pmatrix}u^{1/2}(p)~~\mid &u^{-1/2}(p)~~\mid & v^{-1/2}(p)~~\mid&v^{1/2}(p)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{\sigma(p)}&\sqrt{\sigma(p)}\\\sqrt{\overline{\sigma}(p)}&-\sqrt{\overline{\sigma}(p)}\end{pmatrix}$$
where $\sigma(p)=\begin{pmatrix}p^0+p^3&p^1-ip^2\\p^1+ip^2&p^0-p^3\end{pmatrix}~$, $~\overline{\sigma}(p)=\sigma(p^0,-\vec{p})$, and $\sqrt{~~}$ denotes the square root of a Hermitian matrix. The map $\sigma$ from 4-vectors to Hermitian matrices has an inverse given by $(\sigma^{-1}\hspace{0.035cm}A)^\mu=\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}\left(A\hspace{0.05cm}\sigma_\mu\right)$, and using this correspondence the Lorentz transformation $\Lambda(A)$ is defined by $$\Lambda(A)p=\sigma^{-1}\big(A~\sigma(p)~A^*\big)$$
Putting all this together, we have
$$\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{\sigma(p)}&\sqrt{\sigma(p)}\\\sqrt{\overline{\sigma}(p)}&-\sqrt{\overline{\sigma}(p)}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_{1/2}&\alpha_{-1/2}&0&0\\\beta_{1/2}&\beta_{-1/2}&0&0\\0&0&\gamma_{-1/2}&\gamma_{1/2}\\0&0&\delta_{-1/2}&\delta_{1/2}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}A&0\\0&(A^\dagger)^{-1}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{A^{-1}\sigma(p)(A^\dagger)^{-1}}&\sqrt{A^{-1}\sigma(p)(A^\dagger)^{-1}}\\\sqrt{A^\dagger\overline{\sigma}(p)A}&-\sqrt{A^\dagger\overline{\sigma}(p)A}\end{pmatrix}$$
Solving for the coefficients (eventually) yields
$$\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_{1/2}&\alpha_{-1/2}&0&0\\\beta_{1/2}&\beta_{-1/2}&0&0\\0&0&\gamma_{-1/2}&\gamma_{1/2}\\0&0&\delta_{-1/2}&\delta_{1/2}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{\sigma(p)}^{-1}A\sqrt{A^{-1}\sigma(p)(A^\dagger)^{-1}}&0\\0&\sqrt{\sigma(p)}^{-1}A\sqrt{A^{-1}\sigma(p)(A^\dagger)^{-1}}\end{pmatrix}$$
Here's where I am stuck. In the special case that $A=(A^\dagger)^{-1}$ is unitary (corresponding to when $\Lambda(A)$ is a pure rotation), then we can use the fact that $B\sqrt{C}B^{-1}=\sqrt{BCB^{-1}}$ to simplify
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\sigma(p)}^{-1}A\sqrt{A^{-1}\sigma(p)(A^\dagger)^{-1}}&=\sqrt{\sigma(p)}^{-1}A\sqrt{A^{-1}\sigma(p)~(A^\dagger)^{-1}}A^\dagger A
\\
&=\sqrt{\sigma(p)}^{-1}\sqrt{AA^{-1}\sigma(p)~(A^\dagger)^{-1}A^\dagger}A
\\
&=\sqrt{\sigma(p)}^{-1}\sqrt{\sigma(p)}A\\&=A
\end{align*}
So in this special case, we have
$$\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_{1/2}&\alpha_{-1/2}&0&0\\\beta_{1/2}&\beta_{-1/2}&0&0\\0&0&\gamma_{-1/2}&\gamma_{1/2}\\0&0&\delta_{-1/2}&\delta_{1/2}\end{pmatrix}=D(A)$$
and so the transformation law seems to work out. However, for general $A$, I have no idea how to deal with the square root expression. I've run some examples such as $A=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$ on a computer which seems to prove that the transformation law (as I understand it) doesn't hold for boosts. Where am I going wrong? I would greatly appreciate any help!

And what is $U(A)$?

$U(A)$ is a unitary which acts on an element $f(p)$ of the Hilbert space via $U(A)f=D(A)f(\Lambda(A)^{-1}p)$

"I have found several sources which take this identity as a postulate" What sources? The identity looks suspicious to me: $\psi(x)$ is probably a Dirac spinor, so it is a column matrix, so how can it be multiplied by the unitary matrix from the right?
